# Committing my master to their branches

Tags: git, github

Lets say I have a master website called **A**.

Then I have three individual programmers make their own branches of **A**; lets call them **B**, **C**, and **D**. They are only making individual aesthetic-related coding changes to see how **B**, **C**, and **D** look in action with different visual changes. In other words, they all have the same functionality but maybe we swapped buttons, text fields, 3D objects, etc. just to see if our idea for one branch looks better than another.

As I make functional changes to **A**, how can I push the code for those changes across **B**, **C**, and **D** so that the new features are implemented into their projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't push it to them. You push it to master and they pull it to their own codes. At least, that's my understanding, using bitbucket. I think in GitHub you submit a "pull request", which tells them to review and consider pulling it.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called merging. What you should do if you really want to push your changes to them is add their repository as a remote, fetch the changes they've made, merge your work with theirs. I can't give you any more specifics on how to do each of those steps because I don't know exactly how your system is setup. [This website](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) is a fantastic resource and should have all the info you need to do this .

I should also mention that a workflow where each of the developers is responsible for pushing changes that ought to be made common to each of the other developers is almost universally a bad idea and will lead to errors. I would recommend a setup where there is a central repository that everyone pulls from and pushes to. If your developers work diverges they can use branches to separate the changes made. When you have made changes to the common parts of the website you can push them to the central server and either merge your work with your developers' branches or have them be responsible for merging. The link above should have all the info you need to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

You would push your changes to A. It is up to the individual developers to keep their local versions of A up to date with the remote version. It is also up to the individual developers to keep their own branches (B, C, or D) up to date with the latest changes in A.